# Poor selfie segmentation with Google ML Kit

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, google-vision, google-mlkit

I am using Google ML Kit to do selfie segmentation (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/selfie-segmentation). However, the output am getting is exteremely poor -

Initial image:

[image]

Segmented image with overlay: Observe how the woman's hair is marked pink and the gym equipment and surrounds near her legs are marked non-pink. Even her hands are marked pink (meaning its a background).

[image]

When this is overlayed on another image, to create a background removal effect, it looks terrible

[image]

The segmentation mask returned by the ML Kit has confidence of 1.0 for all the above non-pink areas, meaning its absolutely certain that the areas non-pink are part of the person!!

Am seeing this for several images, not just this one. Infact, the performance (confidence) is pretty poor for an image segmenter.

Question is - is there a way to improve it, maybe by providing a different/better model? If I use something like the PixelLib, the segmentation is way better, albeit the performance of the library is not low latency, hence can't be run on the mobile.

Any pointers/help regardig this would be really appreciated.

Comment: also consider the stack exchanges for AI/ML. stack overflow prefers to have a programming component to the issue. your issue appears to be purely methods and design choices.

Comment: Are you trying this on Android or iOS?

Comment: I've tried this on Android.

Comment: This can be related to the training data of the current ML Kit selfie segmentation model. The training images are "selfies" instead of general images with people in it.      Are you looking for general person segmentation?    Is there anything else in common for your use cases?

Comment: general person segmentation is needed, which includes a selfie and/or photo taken of an individual from a close up. Idea is then to be able to take the segmented image and apply it to a different background, as shown in the images attached

Comment: If you have time, can you please explain how to replace overlay with a image? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75054727/virtual-background Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be too optimistic to expect a lightweight real-time CPU-based selfie model to provide accurate segmentation results for a pretty complex and in a way tricky scene (pose, black color of the background and outfit).

[Official example](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/selfie-segmentation) highlights the fact complex environments will likely to be a problem.

[image]

The only "simple" way of processing your scene is to use depth estimation. Just did a quick test with a pretty complex model:

[image]

Results are too far from being usable (at least in a fully automated way).
There are several other options:

- Create a custom more sport-oriented model, trained on a proper dataset
- Use a heavier model (modern phones are quite capable)
- Use some reliable pose estimation in order to make sure a particular scene is selfie-compatible

[image]