# Virtual background

Tags: android, google-mlkit

How do I add an image as a virtual background using ML Kit Selfie segmentation? I am following the example project from github and I got it working with a colored overlay. But I dont understand how to replace that overlay with a picture. In this question, I can see that it is possible: [Poor selfie segmentation with Google ML Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910889/poor-selfie-segmentation-with-google-ml-kit). I copied code from https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart to get the pink overlay. I should also mention that I am using this in streaming mode.

Comment: This maybe helpful: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/issues/610